# How can organocuprates generated with catalytic Cu(I) be competitive in 1,4-addition to an enone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds, regioselectivity

Organocopper compounds (e.g. $\ce{LiCuR_2}$) are often prepared from an organolithium or Grignard reagent when a soften nucleophile is needed, such as for a conjugate addition to an $\alpha,\beta$-unsaturated carbonyl. Clayden et al. (p.499) recommend generating it *in situ* catalytically via transmetallation with 1% $\ce{CuI}$.

My question: if at the start, there is 1% of organocopper reagent and 99% Grignard reagent, why don't those 99% do direct addition? Why is the organocopper reagent so much more reactive that conjugate addition is the main outcome of the reaction?

Comment: My guess would be the greater nucleophilicity of the cupr**ate** over the $\ce{R-Mg-X}$

Comment: @EashaanGodbole Thanks! But why is it more nucleophilic?

Comment: The formation of -ate complexes (e.g. boronate, aluminate (as in $\ce{LiAlH4}$) results in the formation of high-energy $\sigma$-bonds. There's the extra reduction in effective electronegativity due to the negative charge too...

Comment: @EashaanGodbole But isn’t the C-Mg bond higher in energy than C-Cu?

Comment: Would it be higher in energy than $\ce{C-Cu^{-}}$?

Comment: You assume the rates of reaction are nearly equal. Since 1,4-addition of the Cu-reagent is highly efficient relative to 1,2-addition of a Grignard reagent (say, ~10:1) AND you have only 1% Cu, then the formation of the Cu-reagent and conjugate addition is at least 1000 times faster than 1,2-Grignard addition.

Comment: Sorry could you please explain: (1) why the 1,4 addition is highly efficient, (2) how you get those 1000. Thanks!

Comment: @EashaanGodbole Do you mean that $\ce{C-Cu^{-}}$ is higher in energy than $\ce{C-Mg^{+}}$? It might be! But that would also imply that the C is more $\delta-$. Isn’t the whole point of using Cu is that it’s more electronegative and so can reduce the electron density around C, making it less hard to disfavor direct addition?

Comment: Related: Hard-Soft Acid-Base (HSAB) Theory

Comment: @EashaanGodbole Could you please clarify what you mean exactly? Like the whole of your argument? Sorry, I still don’t follow